# Sorting array that is read from a file

Tags: java, sorting

First time user so sorry if I do something wrong.

I have to write a program that will sort an array depending on what the user enters. The data is read from a file. The file `Bank.txt` holds **10,000** accounts some are empty accounts with a default value of `0000, ,00.00.`

Currently the output is:

```
ID#1234 joe     $436.0
ID#3620 kim     $600.0
ID#4563 Jimmy   $1653.0
ID#4571 Billy   $72.0
ID#5930 Brian   $962.0
ID#6766 Jen     $215.0
ID#7092 Adam    $8794.0
```

It only looks like it is sorted by the `ID` because that is the way it is written in the txt document.  I am not sure where to even begin. I need to sort by `ID` or `Name` or `Balance` depending on what the user enters. I know there is the `array.sort(array)` but that wouldn't work here (unless im over thinking it) because it would only sort the current `id,name,balance` in that array. Again any help would be appreciated Thanks.

Sort by name should display:

```
ID#7092 Adam    $8794.0
ID#4571 Billy   $72.0
ID#5930 Brian   $962.0
ID#6766 Jen     $215.0
ID#4563 Jimmy   $1653.0
ID#1234 joe     $436.0
ID#3620 kim     $600.0
```

Sort by balance:

```
ID#4571 Billy   $72.0 <br>
ID#6766 Jen     $215.0 <br>
ID#1234 joe     $436.0 <br>
ID#3620 kim     $600.0 <br>
ID#5930 Brian   $962.0 <br>
ID#4563 Jimmy   $1653.0 <br>
ID#7092 Adam    $8794.0 <br>
```

Program code:

```
import static java.nio.file.AccessMode.*;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ReadBankSequentially
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Path file = Paths.get("Bank.txt");
        String[] array = new String[3];
        String s = "";
        String delimiter = ",";
        int id;
        String stringId;
        String name;
        double balance;

        try
        {

            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(Files.newInputStream(file));
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
            System.out.println();
            s = reader.readLine();
            while(s != null)
            {
                array = s.split(delimiter);
                stringId = array[0];
                id = Integer.parseInt(array[0]);
                if(id != 0)
                {
                    name = array[1];
                    balance = Double.parseDouble(array[2]);
                    System.out.println("ID#" + stringId + " " + name + " $" + balance); 

                }
                s = reader.readLine();
            }
            reader.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Message: " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: doo you have an own class for your accounts? then you could use `Arrays.sort(array, comparator) and implement different comparators for your tasks, see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28T[],%20java.util.Comparator%29 and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a `Customer` [DTO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object):

```
public class Customer {
  protected int _id;
  protected String _name;
  protected float _balance;

  public Customer() {
    init(0, "New Customer", 0.00f);
  }

  public Customer(int id, String name, float balance) {
    init(id, name, balance);
  }

  private void init(int id, String name, float balance) {
    id(id).name(name).balance(balance);
  }

  public int id() {
    return this._id;
  }
  public Customer id(int id) {
    this._id = id;
    return this;
  }

  public String name() {
    return this._name;
  }
  public Customer name(String name) {
    this._name = name;
    return this;
  }

  public float balance() {
    return this._balance;
  }
  public Customer balance(float balance) {
    this._balance = balance;
    return this;
  }

  public String toString() {
    return String.format("#%d: %-5s - $%07.2f", id(), name(), balance());
  }
}
```

Next I would create a utility class that reads the file and generates customers:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Utils {  
  public static List<Customer> getCustomers(String filename, String delimiters) {
    List<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<Customer>();
    Customer customer = null;
    File file = new File(filename);
    Scanner scanner = null;
    try {
      scanner = new Scanner(file);
      while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        if ((customer = createCustomer(line, delimiters)) != null)
          customers.add(customer);
      }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
      scanner.close();
    }

    return customers;
  }

  public static Customer createCustomer(String line, String delimiter) {
    String[] arr = line.split(delimiter);
    if (arr.length < 3)
      return null;
    int id = Integer.parseInt(arr[0].trim());
    String name = arr[1].trim();
    float balance = Float.parseFloat(arr[2].trim());
    return new Customer(id, name, balance);
  }
}
```

Finally I would create my `Bank` class which stores `Customer`s and can sort/print them out.

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import static bank.Utils.getCustomers;

public class Bank {
  protected List<Customer> customers;

  public enum Sort {
    ID, NAME, BALANCE
  }

  public Bank() {
    String filename = "bank/Bank.txt";
    String delimiters = "[,]";
    customers = getCustomers(filename, delimiters);

    printCustomers(Sort.ID, false);
    printCustomers(Sort.ID, true);
    printCustomers(Sort.NAME, false);
    printCustomers(Sort.NAME, true);
    printCustomers(Sort.BALANCE, false);
    printCustomers(Sort.BALANCE, true);
  }

  public void sortId(boolean descending) {
    final int d = descending ? -1 : 1;
    Comparator<Customer> comparator = new Comparator<Customer>() {
      public int compare(Customer c1, Customer c2) {
        return (c1.id() > c2.id() ? 1 :
               c1.id() == c2.id() ? 0 : -1) * d;
      }
    };
    Collections.sort(customers, comparator);
  }

  public void sortName(boolean descending) {
    final int d = descending ? -1 : 1;
    Comparator<Customer> comparator = new Comparator<Customer>() {
      public int compare(Customer c1, Customer c2) {
        return (c1.name().compareTo(c2.name())) * d;
      }
    };
    Collections.sort(customers, comparator);
  }

  public void sortBalance(boolean descending) {
    final int d = descending ? -1 : 1;
    Comparator<Customer> comparator = new Comparator<Customer>() {
      public int compare(Customer c1, Customer c2) {
        return (c1.balance() > c2.balance() ? 1 :
               c1.balance() == c2.balance() ? 0 : -1) * d;
      }
    };
    Collections.sort(customers, comparator);
  }

  public void printCustomers(Sort sortBy, boolean descending) {
    String header = "";
    String desc = descending ? "descending" : "ascending";
    switch (sortBy) {
      case NAME:
        header = "Sorting by Name";
        sortName(descending);
        break;
      case BALANCE:
        header = "Sorting by Balance";
        sortBalance(descending);
        break;
      case ID:
        header = "Sorting by Id";
      default:
        sortId(descending);
        break;
    }
    System.out.printf("### %s %s ###\n", header, desc);
    for (Customer c : customers)
      System.out.println(c);
    System.out.println();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Bank();
  }
}
```

**Input File**

```
1234,Joe,436.00
3620,Kim,600.00
4563,Jimmy,1653.00
4571,Billy,72.00
5930,Brian,962.00
6766,Jen,215.00
7092,Adam,8794.00
```

**Output**

```
### Sorting by Id ascending ###
#1234: Joe   - $0436.00
#3620: Kim   - $0600.00
#4563: Jimmy - $1653.00
#4571: Billy - $0072.00
#5930: Brian - $0962.00
#6766: Jen   - $0215.00
#7092: Adam  - $8794.00

### Sorting by Id descending ###
#7092: Adam  - $8794.00
#6766: Jen   - $0215.00
#5930: Brian - $0962.00
#4571: Billy - $0072.00
#4563: Jimmy - $1653.00
#3620: Kim   - $0600.00
#1234: Joe   - $0436.00

### Sorting by Name ascending ###
#7092: Adam  - $8794.00
#4571: Billy - $0072.00
#5930: Brian - $0962.00
#6766: Jen   - $0215.00
#4563: Jimmy - $1653.00
#1234: Joe   - $0436.00
#3620: Kim   - $0600.00

### Sorting by Name descending ###
#3620: Kim   - $0600.00
#1234: Joe   - $0436.00
#4563: Jimmy - $1653.00
#6766: Jen   - $0215.00
#5930: Brian - $0962.00
#4571: Billy - $0072.00
#7092: Adam  - $8794.00

### Sorting by Balance ascending ###
#4571: Billy - $0072.00
#6766: Jen   - $0215.00
#1234: Joe   - $0436.00
#3620: Kim   - $0600.00
#5930: Brian - $0962.00
#4563: Jimmy - $1653.00
#7092: Adam  - $8794.00

### Sorting by Balance descending ###
#7092: Adam  - $8794.00
#4563: Jimmy - $1653.00
#5930: Brian - $0962.00
#3620: Kim   - $0600.00
#1234: Joe   - $0436.00
#6766: Jen   - $0215.00
#4571: Billy - $0072.00
```

Comment: It would be better to seek other pages that uses Java 5 or later. This implementation for `Comparator` works but you can use the advantage of [generics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java) to simplify the code.

Answer (score 0):

Create an "AccountEntry" class:

```
class AccountEntry {
  String id;
  String name;
  int balance;
}
```

Create three "Comparators":

```
class IdComparator implements java.lang.Comparator {
  public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
    AccountEntry a1 = (AccountEntry) o1;
    AccountEntry a2 = (AccountEntry) o2;
    return a1.id.compareTo(a2.id);
  }
}

class NameComparator implements java.lang.Comparator {
  public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
    AccountEntry a1 = (AccountEntry) o1;
    AccountEntry a2 = (AccountEntry) o2;
    return a1.name.compareTo(a2.name);
  }
}

class BalanceComparator implements java.lang.Comparator {
  public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
    AccountEntry a1 = (AccountEntry) o1;
    AccountEntry a2 = (AccountEntry) o2;
    if (a1.balance > a2.balance)
      return 1;
    if (a1.balance == a2.balance)
      return 0;
    return -1;
  }
}
```

Sort using

```
Collections.sort(List, comparator)
```

Comment: Looks like you're living in the past. Since Java 5 you have [generics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java) (that dates from 2004, almost 10 years ago)

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to save the data in an structure (class) that will contain enough data to support the incoming data from the file. Let's call it `BankAccount` class:

```
public class BankAccount {
    //NOTE: you can change the type of the elements used here, like double per BigDecimal
    private long id;
    private String owner;
    private double amount;
    //class constructors...
    //getters and setters...
}
```

Second, you need to store these objects in a structure that can be sorted like an array or a `List`. I will recommend a `List<BankAccount>`:

```
public class Bank {
    private List<BankAccount> accounts = new ArrayList<BankAccount>();
    //getters and setters...
}
```

Third, you have to sort the arrays. If you're in learning phase, you will need to implement an algorithm to sort your array. If you're somewhat experienced with Java, you can use [`Collections#sort(List, Comparator)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) and send your `List<BankAccount> accounts` as first parameter and a `Comparator<BankAccount>` as second parameter. I'll define an example of the comparator to sort the accounts based on the account owner name (using [anonymous class](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch03_12.htm)):

```
public void sortByOwner() {
    Comparator<BankAccount> comparator = new Comparator<BankAccount>() {
        public int compare(BankAccount account1, BankAccount account2) {
            return account1.getOwner().compareTo(account2.getOwner());
        }
    };
    Collections.sort(accounts, comparator);
}
```

Comment: Thank you all you were very helpful

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity, define a `User` type:

```
class User
{
    public int id;
    public String name;
    public double balance;

    public User(int id, int name, int balance)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.balance = balance;
    }
}
```

Then define `Comparator` type for it (as you can have different comparison rules):

```
class UserComparatorByBalance implements Comparator<User>
{
    public int compare(User a, User b)
    {
        if (a.balance > b.balance) return 1; // or -1
        if (a.balance < b.balance) return -1; // or 1
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Then, populate a collection (list):

```
        ArrayList<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
        s = reader.readLine();
        while(s != null)
        {
            array = s.split(delimiter);
            stringId = array[0];
            id = Integer.parseInt(array[0]);
            if(id != 0)
            {
                name = array[1];
                balance = Double.parseDouble(array[2]);
                System.out.println("ID#" + stringId + " " + name + " $" + balance); 
                User user = new User(id, name, balance);
                users.add(user);
            }
            s = reader.readLine();
        }
        reader.close();
```

And, finally, sort:

```
Collections.sort(users, new UserComparatorByBalance());
```